# How to get an Enum's backed type?

Tags: php, enums

I was wondering what is the best way to get an Enum's backed type:

```
enum E: string {
    case a = "A";
    case b = "B";
}
```

I have a function that receives an `Enum` class name as the parameter and inside the function I need to check if the type is backed by `int` or `string` or it is not a `Backed Enum`.

```
//this function can be called like: foo(E::class)
function foo(string $enum) {
    // here I need to check if $enum is backed by int or string or nothing
}
```

I've already tried `get_parent_class`, however it does not work since `Backed Enum`s are not inheriting the back type and they are just closed lists.
I know I can put a static function inside the `Enum` definition and return the type there, but I was wondering if there is a more general and elegant way?

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: Call the `cases()` static method of the class to get a list of cases. Then call the `value()` method of one of the cases to get its value. Check the type of this value.

Comment: @Barmar I'm developing a json validator library and I want to be able to pass an Enum as the type of the field.

Comment: Won't that always be backed by strings like `enum Type: string { case INT = 'integer'; case OBJECT = 'object'; ... }`?

Comment: @Barmar So it was just an example, it should be able to work with all Enums, like if there is enum Type {case a;case b;} or enum Type1: int {case a = 1; case b = 2;}.

Comment: @Barmar I think checking one of the cases' value is the best option that I have. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for a solution, here's an example implementation of @Barmar's suggestion.

**Assuming that your enum has at least a single case.**

```php
enum StringExample: string
{
    case foo = 'foo';
    case bar = 'bar';
}

/**
 * @param class-string<\BackedEnum> $enumClass
 *
 * @return array<int|string>
 */
 function getCaseValues(string $enumClass): array
 {
    return \array_map(
      static fn (\BackedEnum $case): int | string => $case->value,
      $enumClass::cases(),
    );
 }

$enumClass = StringExample::class;

$caseValues = getCaseValues($enumClass);

$isIntEnum = \is_int($this->caseValues[0] ?? null);
$isStringEnum = \is_string($this->caseValues[0] ?? null);
```